# How to follow the method execution in python

Tags: python, oop, method-resolution-order

I am trying to read some source code from some open source python project, like ipython. I often find it hard to follow the execution flow of methods in different classes, even using eclipse's debug tool and execute the code step by step. I don't quite know why the code jumps to certain methods in a distantly related class.

I know that it must be the inheritance hierarchy, but I find it hard to follow. Is there any tools that help to understand how the code executes? Like visualizing the execution order of different methods? Hope it's not a entirely naive question.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen or tried any code graph "profiling" tools?

Comment: @sarnold just tried a python module called pycallgraph and it seems working great.

Answer (score 0):

The jumps are caused by your functions calling another function which in tern calls another function.

Answer (score 0):

MIT website has a program that traces executions and displays them in picture that you may find useful:
http://people.csail.mit.edu/pgbovine/python/tutor.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat as you. In the end I created my own thingy. Namely there are many built-in ways you can use for this but it takes some effort. One such way is setting a *tracer* - some sort of analyzer for the code while it executes.

**Source:**

```
import sys, inspect

class Tracer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tracing_packages = []
        self.whitespace = '    '
        self.indent_lvl = 0

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        # Module info
        mod = inspect.getmodule(frame)
        if mod:
            modpath = mod.__name__
        else:
            modpath = '<no module>'
        # Just return if not interested in package
        for to_trace in self.tracing_packages:
            if not modpath.startswith(to_trace):
                return self.trace
        # Other info
        fn_name = frame.f_code.co_name
        src_lines = inspect.getsource(frame).split('\n')
        src_line_start = src_lines[0]
        src_line_end = src_lines[-1]
        lineno = frame.f_lineno
        ws = self.whitespace
        # Printing
        if event == 'call':
            self.indent_lvl += 1
            print('%scallin: %s %s %s' % (self.indent_lvl*ws, modpath, fn_name, str(arg)))
        elif event == 'return':
            if isinstance(arg, object):
                ret = type(arg)
            else:
                ret = str(arg)
            print('%sreturn: %s' % (self.indent_lvl*ws, ret))
            self.indent_lvl -= 1
        return self.trace

    def watch_package(self, packname):
        self.tracing_packages.append(packname)
```

**Usage**

For your case you just type:

```
tracer = Tracer()
tracer.watch_package('IPython')
sys.settrace(tracer.trace)
```

Then if you try to run a function you will get printed the whole calling chain including any other functions from the same package being called.

**Other example**

I use this when I want to understand the flow of specific functions or of the whole package. If you want an overhead view of the whole package you can also use pyreverse from [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) in order to create UML diagrams.

Anyhow here is an example of tracing the [PyOCD](https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD) package:

```
>>> import sys, inspect, pyOCD
>>> tracer = Tracer()
>>> tracer.watch_package('pyOCD')
>>> sys.settrace(tracer.trace)
>>> pyOCD.board.MbedBoard.listConnectedBoards()
    callin: pyOCD.board.mbed_board listConnectedBoards None
        callin: pyOCD.board.mbed_board getAllConnectedBoards None
            callin: pyOCD.interface.pyusb_backend getAllConnectedInterface
                callin: pyOCD.interface.pyusb_backend __init__ None
                    callin: pyOCD.interface.interface __init__ None
                    return: <type 'NoneType'>
                return: <type 'NoneType'>
                callin: pyOCD.interface.pyusb_backend start_rx None
                return: <type 'NoneType'>
            return: <type 'list'>

            ...
```